# Android RecyclerView scroll to specific word

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrolling

I want to scroll to a specific string or index of text. i get search text position and i want to scroll or focus center of screen to my specific string in `RecyclerView`

I tried to many ways but not solved

now i scroll to like this

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(row, position);
```

but it scroll only row of `RecyclerView`. i need scroll to specific word
can some one help me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

layoutmanager.scrollToPosition(position);

**or**

recycler.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)